# PHP intl can convert a Gregorian date to other calendar type

Tags: php, intl, datetime-conversion, hijri

PHP intl can convert a Gregorian date to other calendar type.

For example Gregorian to Hijri, `2017/04/11` to `1396/01/22`

Or we must use external library to convert dates?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.calendar.php

Answer (score 6):

You Can Use This Method:

```
function getDateTimeFromCalendarToFormat($format = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',     $time = null, $locale = 'fa_IR', $calendar = 'persian', $timeZone = 'Asia/Tehran')
{
    if (empty($time)) {
        $time = new \DateTime();
    }

    $formatter = new \IntlDateFormatter("{$locale}@calendar={$calendar}", \IntlDateFormatter::FULL, \IntlDateFormatter::FULL, $timeZone, \IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL);
    $dateArray = [];

    $formatter->setPattern($format);

    return $formatter->format($time);
}
```

if you call `getDateTimeFromCalendarToFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',null,'en_US')`
**Return**
    `1396-06-27 13:50:21`

if you call `getDateTimeFromCalendarToFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',null,'fa_IR')`
**Return**
    `۱۳۹۶-۰۶-۲۷ ۱۳:۴۹:۵۱`

New pattern string to use. Possible patterns are documented at  [Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)

Comment: why? @mohammad-salehi

Comment: sorry @honarkhah , it was my mistake, or maybe it's a PHP bug. I used 'Y-m-d H:i:s' for $format and it returned a wrong month number every time. but it works fine with 'Y-M-d H:i:s' (capital M). what is the difference between yyyy and Y, or i and mm and other multi letters with single letters?

Comment: @MohammadSalehi You can check http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime , this is a fully example of pattern you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can. This is an example which converts a time object to its Persian formatted string using intl:

```
function c2persian($time, $toCalender = 'persian', $timezone = 'Asia/Tehran', $locale = 'fa_IR') {
    $formatter = IntlDateFormatter::create($locale, NULL, NULL, $timezone, IntlCalendar::createInstance($timezone, "$locale@calendar=$toCalender"));
    return $formatter->format($time);
}
$time = strtotime("2089-08-09 00:00:00 UTC");
echo c2persian($time);
```

You can find more info at [php intlCalendar documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.setcalendar.php).

Answer (score -3):

PHP Already has date format functions, you need to convert first with `strtotime()` function and get the desired values with `date()`

```
<?php
$originalDate = "2017/04/11";

$theDate = strtotime($originalDate);

$theDay = date('d',$theDate);
$theMonth = date('m',$theDate);
$theYear = date('Y',$theDate);

$customFormat = date('Y-m-d',$theDate);
$customFormat2 = date('d/m/Y',$theDate);
$customFormat3 = date('F j, Y, g:i a',$theDate);
?>
```

Example working here: https://eval.in/772416

You can get more info about date in php here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Folks are down voting but not giving any context. The OP was asking about how to convert to a different calendar entirely, not just how to convert the format of the date/time within it's original calendar. Your answer is absolutely correct, just not for this question.