# Incorrect Hijri date in PHP Intl

Tags: php, date, intl, hijri

Today is **27 Ramadan 1438** in Asia/Tehran. but `PHP Intl` says today is **28 Ramadan 1438**.
Anyone know what the problem is?

```
$DateTime = new DateTime();
$IntlDateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
                    'en_US@calendar=islamic',
                    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
                    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
                    'Asia/Tehran',
                    IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL);

echo $IntlDateFormatter->format($DateTime);
```

Comment: i write a helper method for this functionality , can visit : [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43332341/php-intl-can-convert-a-gregorian-date-to-other-calendar-type/46275845#46275845) you can pass Calendar type to them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this: (changed calender from islamic to islamic-civil)

```
$DateTime = new DateTime();
$IntlDateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
                    'en_US@calendar=islamic-civil',
                    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
                    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
                    'Asia/Tehran',
                    IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL);

echo $IntlDateFormatter->format($DateTime);
```

Answer (score 2):

use `islamic-civil` instead of `islamic`