# How to show month name using PHP_intl?

Tags: php, datetime

I keep getting number instead of month name. I need to get the month name like **July**.

```
$formatter = new \IntlDateFormatter(
    "fa_IR@calendar=persian",
    \IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    \IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    'Asia/Tehran',
    \IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL
);
$time = new \DateTime();
$formatter->setPattern('yyyy mm dd');
$formatter->format($time)
```

Comment: please review the official doc, first http://php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.format.php

Comment: please review : http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use MMMM.
All available pattern is on [this link](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)

```
$formatter = new \IntlDateFormatter(
    "fa_IR@calendar=persian",
    \IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    \IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    'Asia/Tehran',
    \IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL
);
$time = new \DateTime();
$formatter->setPattern('yyyy MMMM dd');
$formatter->format($time)
```

This question is same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43332341/php-intl-can-convert-a-gregorian-date-to-other-calendar-type/46275845#46275845)

Answer (score 3):

```
$time = new \DateTime();
$formatter->setPattern('yyyy MMMM dd');
$formatter->format($time)
```

use MMMM to show month name. for more info :
http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17720679)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17720679)

Answer (score 1):

```
$formatter->setPattern('yyyy MMMM dd');
```

For more: http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'no_NB.utf-8', 'nor'); // For other stuff
Locale::setDefault('no_NB.utf-8'); // For IntlDateFormatter

$f = new IntlDateFormatter(null, null, null, null, null, 'd. MMMM y');
echo "Date-". $f->format(new DateTime("2017-10-24"))."<br/>";

$f = new IntlDateFormatter(null, null, null, null, null, 'MMMM');
echo "Month-". $f->format(new DateTime("2017-10-24"));
```

Output:

Date - 24 oktober 2017

Month - oktober