# use field as recursive function in where condition in yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to send content of `date1` to `exp` function in **where()** condition and return the result.

**Note:** Actually I want to compare two date, that I need to change one of dates to explode

Here is my code:

```
function exp($date){
            $date = explode('/', $date);
            $Y = $date[0];
            $m = $date[1];
            $d = $date[2];

            return $Y;
        }

$promise = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Post::find()
            ->where('status = "show"')
            ->andWhere(['<=', exp('date1'), 'date2'])// date1 is: 2018/02/03
            ->orderBy('id'),
            ]);
```

Is there any way else to do this?

Comment: do you have the raw SQL prepared ? as it is confusing what are you trying to achieve

Comment: I trying to send content of `date1` to `exp` function, but here in my code send `date1` as a string

Answer (score 2):

`exp` is a PHP function, in `andWhere` you prepare an SQL query that will run on the SQL server. The SQL parser on the SQL server can not execute PHP functions. You should use MySQL [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function here:

```
$promise = new ActiveDataProvider([
      'query' => Post::find()
         ->where('status = "show"')
         ->andWhere(['<=', 'DATE_FORMAT(date1, "%Y")', 'date2'])
      ->orderBy('id'),
   ]);
```

Please change the name of the fields `date1` and `date2` to make them more informative. For ex. `order_date`, `delivery_date` etc.

If `status` values are often used in your code, you should replace them with a constants of the `Post`class.

If `date2` contains only year values, it is better to use the [YEAR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/year.html) type.

Comment: I nee to send `date1` to `exp`, because `date1` is Persian date, and I need to convert it to Gregorian, but i removed the code in question.

Comment: As  you said it is impossible to use php function in `where`? do you have any idea to convert `date1` to Gregorian date?

Comment: You can write a user defined function for convert MySQL date from Persian to Gregorian, which can take quite a long time. Or you can select rows from database without filtering by date and then convert Persian date in PHP using `IntlDateFormatter::parse` and `IntlDateFormatter::format` methods as in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24092191/7663972). Then compare dates with `DateTime::diff` method.

Comment: unfortunately no, because as said, in this way is imposibble, I used with `foreach` loop for instead of `activeDataProvider`.